# write the main function that takes no parameters and returns nothing

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need to write the main function that takes no parameters and returns nothing. The main function should call the make_periodic_table function and print the returned table with each individual element on a separate line and add a call to the main function. Be certain to protect the call to main with an if statement. but when I tried My output it's not the expected. How Can I solve this ? please.

````
        periodic_table_list = [
            # [symbol, name, atomic_mass]
            ["Ac","Actinium",227],
            ["Ag","Silver",107.8682],
            ["Al","Aluminum",26.9815386],
            ["Am","Americium",243],
            ["Ar","Argon",39.948],
            ["As","Arsenic",74.9216],
            ["At","Astatine",210],
            ["Au","Gold",196.966569],
            ["B","Boron",10.811],
            ["Ba","Barium",137.327],
            ["Be","Beryllium",9.012182],
            ["Bh","Bohrium",272],
            ["Bi","Bismuth",208.9804],
            ["Bk","Berkelium",247],
            ["Br","Bromine",79.904],
            ["C","Carbon",12.0107],
            ["Ca","Calcium",40.078],
            ["Cd","Cadmium",112.411],
            ["Ce","Cerium",140.116],
            ["Cf","Californium",251],
            ["Cl","Chlorine",35.453],
            ["Cm","Curium",247],
            ["Cn","Copernicium",285],
            ["Co","Cobalt",58.933195],
            ["Cr","Chromium",51.9961],
            ["Cs","Cesium",132.9054519],
            ["Cu","Copper",63.546],
            ["Db","Dubnium",268],
            ["Ds","Darmstadtium",281],
            ["Dy","Dysprosium",162.5],
            ["Er","Erbium",167.259],
            ["Es","Einsteinium",252],
            ["Eu","Europium",151.964],
            ["F","Fluorine",18.9984032],
            ["Fe","Iron",55.845],
            ["Fl","Flerovium",289],
            ["Fm","Fermium",257],
            ["Fr","Francium",223],
            ["Ga","Gallium",69.723],
            ["Gd","Gadolinium",157.25],
            ["Ge","Germanium",72.64],
            ["H","Hydrogen",1.00794],
            ["He","Helium",4.002602],
            ["Hf","Hafnium",178.49],
            ["Hg","Mercury",200.59],
            ["Ho","Holmium",164.93032],
            ["Hs","Hassium",270],
            ["I","Iodine",126.90447],
            ["In","Indium",114.818],
            ["Ir","Iridium",192.217],
            ["K","Potassium",39.0983],
            ["Kr","Krypton",83.798],
            ["La","Lanthanum",138.90547],
            ["Li","Lithium",6.941],
            ["Lr","Lawrencium",262],
            ["Lu","Lutetium",174.9668],
            ["Lv","Livermorium",293],
            ["Mc","Moscovium",288],
            ["Md","Mendelevium",258],
            ["Mg","Magnesium",24.305],
            ["Mn","Manganese",54.938045],
            ["Mo","Molybdenum",95.96],
            ["Mt","Meitnerium",276],
            ["N","Nitrogen",14.0067],
            ["Na","Sodium",22.98976928],
            ["Nb","Niobium",92.90638],
            ["Nd","Neodymium",144.242],
            ["Ne","Neon",20.1797],
            ["Nh","Nihonium",284],
            ["Ni","Nickel",58.6934],
            ["No","Nobelium",259],
            ["Np","Neptunium",237],
            ["O","Oxygen",15.9994],
            ["Og","Oganesson",294],
            ["Os","Osmium",190.23],
            ["P","Phosphorus",30.973762],
            ["Pa","Protactinium",231.03588],
            ["Pb","Lead",207.2],
            ["Pd","Palladium",106.42],
            ["Pm","Promethium",145],
            ["Po","Polonium",209],
            ["Pr","Praseodymium",140.90765],
            ["Pt","Platinum",195.084],
            ["Pu","Plutonium",244],
            ["Ra","Radium",226],
            ["Rb","Rubidium",85.4678],
            ["Re","Rhenium",186.207],
            ["Rf","Rutherfordium",267],
            ["Rg","Roentgenium",280],
            ["Rh","Rhodium",102.9055],
            ["Rn","Radon",222],
            ["Ru","Ruthenium",101.07],
            ["S","Sulfur",32.065],
            ["Sb","Antimony",121.76],
            ["Sc","Scandium",44.955912],
            ["Se","Selenium",78.96],
            ["Sg","Seaborgium",271],
            ["Si","Silicon",28.0855],
            ["Sm","Samarium",150.36],
            ["Sn","Tin",118.71],
            ["Sr","Strontium",87.62],
            ["Ta","Tantalum",180.94788],
            ["Tb","Terbium",158.92535],
            ["Tc","Technetium",98],
            ["Te","Tellurium",127.6],
            ["Th","Thorium",232.03806],
            ["Ti","Titanium",47.867],
            ["Tl","Thallium",204.3833],
            ["Tm","Thulium",168.93421],
            ["Ts","Tennessine",294],
            ["U","Uranium",238.02891],
            ["V","Vanadium",50.9415],
            ["W","Tungsten",183.84],
            ["Xe","Xenon",131.293],
            ["Y","Yttrium",88.90585],
            ["Yb","Ytterbium",173.054],
            ["Zn","Zinc",65.38],
            ["Zr","Zirconium",91.224],
            ]
        
            # [symbol, name, atomic_mass]

SYMBOl_INDEX = 0
NAME_INDEX = 1
ATOMIC_MASS_INDEX = 2
def main():
    print(f'{SYMBOl_INDEX}, {NAME_INDEX}, {ATOMIC_MASS_INDEX}')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main() ```
````

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will have to create a function (make_periodic_table) and then call it within main.

```
def make_periodic_table(PTL):
    for element in PTL:
        print(element)

main():
    make_periodic_table(periodic_table_list)
```

To better explain why yours wasn't working, (I'm not 100% on the error you're getting but) in your print statement in main, you're not referencing anything, it's like pointing to thin air and saying print... it won't work, but if you point to an employee and say print this, they may go print something for you. (not the best analogy but you probably only care about the solution anyways)

also, I'm not sure what your professor meant by "Be certain to protect the call to main with an if statement".  I would add something like this in your main function (replace everything in the main function with this) if no one else replies to this:

```
if periodic_table_list:
    make_periodic_table(periodic_table_list)

else:
    print("cannot find periodic table")
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me.